# How to know if a boolean has not been set(or unset) at all?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, thrift

I have a peculiar problem. I work with Thrift with java at the backend and php on the front end. We have a situation where I ask the user for a boolean value for three variables. The user can either set them to true or false, or not set them at all. On the backend, I store these three values as three bits of a char(1) byte. When I checked, upon initialization, Thrift assigns a false value by default to these variables.

The problem I am facing is, that I want to know when the user does not touch (set or unset) a particular boolean at all. A lot of my bit manipulations depend on this. I don't want to make changes at the user end for this, and rather handle it on my own.

Comment: don't use a boolean datatype if u have 3 options. use an unsigned int. it will be better.

Comment: the "three bits" is bit unclear:) but you also mentioned char(1) so maybe there is possibility that you can have more values than 1 and 0:) try to set initial value to something other than 0,1 e.g. -1 and instead of boolean use integer

Comment: and if you rly want to use a boolean, you will need a flag, which checks if the field has been changed

Comment: `boolean` default value is `false`. `Boolean`, on the other hand, will be `null` default. I do not know if Thrift will set the var to false by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these kinds of problems, you should use user-defined data-type i.e. enums.

Define enums which can hold three value => (TRUE, FALSE and NOT_SET)

This would solve your problem

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out too myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

For handling tri-state booleans in java you have a couple of options.

- use Boolean object: `null` means it is unset
- use and int: `1` for true, '0' for false and '-1' for unset
- use an additional flag next to the boolean value to signal unset

note: since Java 5 you can even use the autoboxing for the first option like this:

```
Boolean myFlag = null;

if (myFlag==null) {
    // unset
}
else if (myFlag) {
    // true
}
else {
    // false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is Thrift if nothing is defined for variable, Thrift defaults to optinReqOut (Optional In, Required Out). Therefore, when you are deserializing, it sees it as missing and sets default value.

Explicitly make the variables optional.

https://twitter.github.io/scrooge/Semantics.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work in Java:
I definition a variable named flag in IDL file like this:

```
optional bool flag;
```

And I use it in a Java class file like this:

```
if (request.isSetFlag()) {
    boolean flag = request.isFlag();
    if (flag) {do something when flag is true;}
    else {do something when flag is false;}
}else{
    do something when flag is null;
}
```